# extract string after first occurrence of pattern AND before another pattern

Tags: regex, r

I have the following string:

```
strings <- c("David, FC; Haramey, S; Devan, IA", 
            "Colin, Matthew J.; Haramey, S",
            "Colin, Matthew")
```

If I want the last initials/givenname for all strings i can use the following:

```
sub(".*, ", "", strings)
[1] "IA"      "S"       "Matthew"
```

This removes everything before the **last** `", "`

However, I am stuck on how to get the the first initials/givenname. I know have to remove everything before the **first** `", "` but then I have to  remove everything after any spaces, semicolons, if any.

To be clear the output I want is:

```
c("FC", "Matthew", "Matthew")
```

Any pointers would be great.

fiddling i can get the first surnames `gsub( " .*$", "", strings )`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use

```
> gsub( "^[^\\s,]+,\\s+([^;.\\s]+).*", "\\1", strings, perl=T)
[1] "FC"      "Matthew" "Matthew"
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/aV0wV7/2)

Explanation:

- `^` - start of string
- `[^\\s,]+` - 1 or more characters other than whitespace or `,`
- `,` - a literal comma
- `\\s+` - 1 or more whitespace
- `([^;.\\s]+)` - Group 1 matching 1 or more characters other than `;`, `.` or whitespace
- `.*` - zero or more any character other than a newline

If you want to use a POSIX-like expression, replace `\\s` inside the character classes (inside `[...]`) with `[:blank:]` (or `[:space:]`):

```
gsub( "^[^[:blank:],]+,\\s+([^;.[:blank:]]+).*", "\\1", strings)
```

Comment: Thank yopu for the demo as well as the answer, so I can try grok this.

Comment: +1 for commenting each part of the regex. That way it becomes less of black-magic to us, the uninitiated ;)